# Why doesn't my inner function have access to an object variable defined in its parent function?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to create a simple countdown timer but I am having a scope problem that I would have thought should work.

Why doesn't my inner function have access to an object variable defined in its parent function?

The JavaScript console keeps saying undefined.

```
function test() {
        var minutes = document.getElementById("minutesInput").value;

        var displayMinutesObj = document.getElementById("displayMinutes");

        displayMinutesObj.innerHTML = minutes;

        function timey() {
        console.log( displayMinutesObj.value );
        }

        setInterval(timey,1000); 
    }
```

Comment: So perhaps the element with id "displayMinutes" is not an input field (anymore)? If it didn't have access to the object itself, it would have raised an error.

Comment: What's `displayMinutesObj.innerHTML = minutes;` supposed to do, anyway?

Comment: If there was a scoping problem, the console would display a ReferenceError.

Comment: It does! What does  `console.log( displayMinutesObj);` display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this line `displayMinutesObj.innerHTML = minutes;`, i assume that the element is not input element, hence you cannot use `.value`, as .value property applies to form elements, so change to:

```
..
function timey() {
    console.log( displayMinutesObj.innerHTML );
}
..
```

Comment: Wow!  I looked at that SO many times I didn't get that!  Thank you so much!